# Как организовать систему личных сообщений?

Tags: php, mysql, dialog

Есть регистрация и авторизация. Есть таблица USERS (с пользователями), таблица DIALOGS (для вывода диалогов), таблица MESSAGES (сообщения хранятся в ней).

Суть в выводе сообщений как в диалогах Вконтакте, будто бы чат.
Как правильно организовать вывод?
Привожу код.

```html
<?php


if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
//Подключаемся к базе данных
    include("bd.php");
 
//Записываем все в переменные
    $go=$_GET['id'];



$use=$_SESSION['login'];
$usrid=$_SESSION['id'];
// $delbtn = '<button class="btnDeleteAction" name="delete" onClick="callCrudAction(`delete`,echo $comments[$k]["id"];)">Delete</button>';
//Выбираем все сообщения
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id_user='$go' order by komu='$usrid' ");

//Выводим все сообщения на экран
while($d=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{ 
  echo '
  
  <div class="main-message-box ">
          <div class="message-dt">
           <div class="message-inner-dt">
            <p>'.$d["message"].'</p>
           </div>
           
          </div>
          
         </div>';
         
         
       
}
}

?>
```

получаем $_GET запрос с айди пользователя, с кем у нас диалог.
в таблице MESSAGES столбцы: id(айди сообщения), message (сообщение), id_user (от кого. записывается ID пользователя кто отправил.), komu (айди пользователя, кому отправили).
пытался сделать вывод таким способом как выше привел. в чем проблема?
прилагаю скриншот того, как выглядят сообщения.
проблема в том, что по гет запросу айди 6 (это собеседник допустим, выводятся только его сообщения). по запросу гет айди 5 (мой айди), выводятся только мои сообщения. операторы OR, AND, XOR пробовал, с AND не работает. как правильно сравнить столбцы и вывести все сообщения с пользователем, ну и мои соответственно?

писать про что я использую php 5.6 не надо, знаю что пора переходить на 7 .
это к слову о mysql или mysqli..
[image: ///]

Comment: Нужно сгруппировать WHERE где (`id_user=1 и komu=2`) ИЛИ (`id_user=2 и komu=1`) тем самым мы получим диалог 2-х пользователей и отсортировать их по id (так сказать по моменту записи в таблицу) и вывести результат, как это реализовать почитайте документацию запросов MySQL

Comment: или, то есть WHERE? попробую

Comment: ругается на строчку с while

Comment: Попробуйте так: `SELECT * FROM 'MESSAGES' WHERE ('id_user'=1 AND 'komu'=2) OR ('id_user'=2 AND 'komu'=1) ORDER BY 'id';` только кавычки замените

Comment: успел до вашего сообщения сообразить, что нужен оператор OR в данном случае. за наводку спасибо, без неё никак бы не понял :)

Comment: есть вопрос , на этот раз последний. как сделать, чтобы сообщения которые пришли были слева, а которые мои справа? у меня есть в стилях два вида. мол left и right . но это уже стили. то есть. <div class="message-dt"> - это слева. <div class="message-dt ya"> - это справа. как их разделить? снова делать цикл с сообщениями? но тогда же буду выводиться все и мои и его(собеседника).

Comment: Естественно нужно учитывать входные данные где вы берете собеседника из `$_GET['id']` и свой id пользователя из сессии/куков, если вы используете поочередно блоки и просто меняется класс `left`, `right`, то просто можно сделать сравнение и вставлять определенный класс в зависимости от того, кто отправитель

Comment: я вам премного благодарен. попробую теперь сам разобраться. методом "тыка" что нибудь да получится. спасибо большое!  если будут вопросы, смогу ли я лично к вам обратиться?

Comment: да, конечно, пробуйте и если проблема, помните, лучше спросить чем потратить много времени и нервов и забить, чем решить проблему как бы то не стало и идти дальше!!!

Comment: я с 14 лет себя пробую в flash приложениях. сейчас есть готовая игра на html5. и две недоделаны. помнится чат на php & mysql написал в 15 лет. решил вспомнить какого это, вот сижу уже 3 дня, пишу скрипт фриланса (ну, сайт целый типа как kwork.ru) сделала многое, отклики, запросы услуг, предложения услуг, личный кабинет, баланс, профили пользователей.) но вот здесь встал. спасибо, теперь могу идти дальше.

Comment: вы здесь часто? я готов вам платить за вашу помощь, скажем так, за знания, которые буду впитывать в себя.

Comment: Напишите мне в ICQ, который указан в профиле, я готов помогать если человек действительно хочет вникать, делать, и познавать, но не готов решать задачи за студентов ))

Comment: хорошо. да я не студент. бросил школу в 9 классе. мне 23 скоро отроду. напишу. спасибо!